# Can I force IE9 *from the user side* to operate in quirks/standards mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode, ie8-browser-mode

I've looked at a dozen different "force IE9 quirks/standards mode" questions, and none of them answer what I'm trying to find out.

I want to force the IE9 that's installed on my Windows machine to use quirks mode (or IE9 Standards Mode, or whatever mode).  How do I do this IN THE BROWSER SETTINGS?

That's right: I **DO NOT** want to know how to change page HTML to tell the browser to operate in mode X or Y.  (I already know how to do that!)  I want to configure MY browser to always view everything it sees in mode X or Y, even on pages I don't control the source for.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use the registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
```

Add the following name:

```
iexplore.exe
```

Give it a value of 5,7, or 8 to force each respective mode.

**References**

- [Feature Controls: Browser Emulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730#browser_emulation)
- [Understanding Compatibility Modes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx)